# MySQL FORWARD ENGINEERING

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-workbench

When I am trying to forward engineer my database schema, the workbench is forwarding only 7tables when I am having a total of 17tables. 
So what could be the possible reasons for the problem.

*The connections are all correct - "I tried testing it"
*The database is fine. 
*I am using the mysql server 5.1 for MySQL workbench 6.0.2

Thank You for your time. (y)

Comment: did the export process ends gracefully without errors..?
and when you say 7 tables, you checked there are only 7 CREATE TABLE script inside the exported file..?

Comment: Thank You @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉 for the quick reply.
The export process did end with one error. ["Error about not able to create one table"]. And inside the script there were all the complete 
17tables script.

Comment: could you elaborate on that error message..? I'm still blind here..

Comment: The error message was:
"ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table 'db_rps.module' (errno: 121)"
"SQL script execution finished: statements: 12 succeeded, 1 failed"

That was the only error message that i recieved.

Comment: Hey @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉 : Could it be that I am having same FK names across the schema. Or something to do with the synchronizing.

Comment: maybe the problem is probably you are using FK which refers to a non primary key field.. thus, probably you need to add an additional script there (if you wanna keep your schema)..

Comment: Thank you @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉 for helping me out...
Problem solved... (y)

Comment: @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉, please post your suggestion as answer so that Pelay can accept it and you get the reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe the problem is probably you are using FK which refers to a non primary key field.. thus, probably you need to add an additional script there (if you wanna keep your schema)..

I posted it here again as @Mike Lischke's suggestion..

Comment: Thank U @Mike Lischke and Yohaneskhosiawan. :D